# How does Imagick::recolorImage function work?

Tags: php, imagemagick

I have been looking in documentation, but it is poorly described that it can take matrix as argument. There is no explanation at all what is the meaning of parameters. To be honest there is one example which takes array of 9 values for an argument which is so more confusing.

Where can I find decent materials about this? Maybe someone know how to use this properly and can explain?

Comment: No idea, but I found the source if you want to see yourself.. [line 1740](https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick/blob/3acc635fe321bde7e2154f0cd01e6aa7d970bc3f/imagick_class.c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ImageMagick command line, recolor was change to color-matrix and can be found at http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#color-matrix. But a good reference to how it works is at http://designstacks.net/color-matrix, which has an interactive tool. Also see examples at http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#color-matrix

Basically, colors are represented as fractions in the range 0 to 1.

For a 3x3 matrix, each row represents the fraction of input red, input green and input blue that will be mixed (added) to form the output color. The first row computes the output red, the second row computes the output green and third row computes the output blue.

More columns are used for alpha and for bias (extra last column, if desired). More rows are for CMYK or CMYKA.

1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1

is a no-op. The output will be the same as the input.